# how to Get List of all instances of specific Struct

Tags: racket

I trying to figure it out, how to get list of all instances of specific struct let say: empInfo is my struct name and it could have more than three instances. Because instance names are dynamic. Thus, i need to listing name of instance using for loop or any field's value of all instances.
Are struct is relate to its instance in which point i will get it.

At last, i need FNAME of all instances of specific struct.

```
(struct empInfo(FNAME LNAME IDNO PHONE EMAIL)#:mutable)

(define PersonOne(empInfo "S" "R" 13 "+44" "A@email.com"))
(define PersonTwo(empInfo "H" "I" 31 "+44" "H@email.com"))
(define PersonThree(empInfo "A" "Q" 1 "+44" "S@email.com"))

(define ilist(list (empInfo-FNAME PersonOne) (empInfo-FNAME PersonTwo) (empInfo-FNAME PersonThree)))
```

on interaction window

> ```
> > ilist
> '("S" "H" "A")
> ```

I just wanted to do it with loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, we'd use `map` for this:

```
(define people (list PersonOne PersonTwo PersonThree))
(map empInfo-FNAME people)
=> '("S" "H" "A")
```

If you're looking for a solution from scratch, just loop over the list and apply `empInfo-FNAME` on each element, building a new list as output:

```
(define (first-names lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      '()
      (cons (empInfo-FNAME (car lst))
            (first-names (cdr lst)))))

(first-names people)
=> '("S" "H" "A")
```

Comment: Amazing: how it is iterating, i means pratically it is loop. but how it is happing. S, H and A are belong to different instances. can i use for-loop in between.

Comment: This is how you "iterate" in Scheme, by doing a recursion. Forget about for loops :) things work different in Scheme. I suggest a good book to get used to it, like "How to Design Programs" or "The Little Schemer". To work on different instances of a struct, you _must_ put them in a list, that's what I did with `people`.